# Python version or Keras?

Tags: python, keras

This is my deep learning model using Keras to predict the quality of wine (wine dataset)

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(11, input_shape=(11,), activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
# Compile model 
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae']) 
# Fit the model 
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50, batch_size=10) 
# evaluate the model 
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y) print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % 
(model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100)).
```

When I use anaconda with python 2.7 it works but when I use anaconda with python 3.6 it gives error like this:
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (11,1) into shape (11). 
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Try `X=X.reshape((-1,11))`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I am using DataFrame and got this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Comment: Hmmm.... then perhaps `input_shape=(11,1)`.

Comment: I tried it already and got:ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (11,1) into shape (11)

Comment: which line throws the error? what is your keras version?

Comment: Thank you pietz for your attention. The keras version is 2.1.1 and the error comes from this line:   model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50, batch_size=10)

Comment: What are the shapes if X and Y? And have you tried it without specifying an input shape? Sequential models can often work it out themselves. Happy to have a look if you shared a working script and dataset